# How do I enable Scroll Lock?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, lock

I need to enable scroll lock so I can toggle lights on my keyboard.
This works on Arch.Funny thing it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

http://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/getting-scroll-lock-to-work-in-ubuntu/

```
$ xmodmap -e ‘add mod3 = Scroll_Lock’
xmodmap:  unknown command on line commandline:1
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'mod3' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file '=' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'Scroll_Lock’' for reading
xmodmap:  4 errors encountered, aborting.
```

Answer (score 31):

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

(Note the difference in the single-quotes!)

Copy this and paste it in a terminal.

Then the error will no longer occur.

I have used this command successfully on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

Comment: This won't work anymore on Gnome 3.10 since it will reset keyboard map after every login and screen lock/unlock

Comment: How do you do this with just xkb instead of xmodmap?

Comment: To any archaeologists: Still works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked on Mint 18!

Comment: Works great on pure debian (testing, latest stable kernel etc) with K700 keyboard

Comment: thank you, it helps me a lot. S2

Answer (score 25):

**Or you can switch the lights with these:**

On:

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

Off:

```
xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
```

Works on Ubuntu 12.04 x86 for my SpeedLink illuminated keyboard (SL-6453-SSV-A).

Comment: How can you use setxkbmap to have scroll lock just work?

Comment: How can you do this automatically when linux boot?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

[Found the permanent way](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,125690.msg1052201.html?PHPSESSID=2qsv83lve6dgd0ivq14bfcjc30#msg1052201) after a long night up with lots of half baked solutions.

```
# backup your symbols file
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us{,.distribution}
```

Add the following line in the `xkb_symbols "basic" {` section. do not worry if that second line is not there, it is only there for some languages and was not there for us on my system.

```
...
    modifier_map Mod3   { Scroll_Lock }; <==<< Add this line

    include "level3(ralt_switch)" <==<< before this line
};
```

You may have to do the same in your other layouts if you switch between languages

Also, there is a cache where xkb layouts live.  You should clear it before restarting your X server to check the new keyboard symbol file(s).

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

Comment: Works on ubuntu 14.04 too (tested with Cooler Master Devastator keyboard)

Comment: ps: you must remove the '<==<< Add this line' part or else you will not have a functional keyboard upon x restart :)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.10. Thanks a bunch, it's been driving me nuts for ages!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 too

Comment: The right place is actually `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. If you edit it, you don't need to edit any layouts files.

Answer (score 0):

If you just modify the

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

you should use a command like

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

and add the line

```
 modifier_map Mod3   { Scroll_Lock };
```

inside the

```
xkb_symbols "pc105" {
```

It's enough