# Function keys disabled after enabling scroll lock

Tags: function-keys

I had enabled the scroll lock key for my illuminated keyboard by using `xmod`,

Now my function keys don't work whenever I enable the scroll lock...
I use the function keys for shortcuts, assistance would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable Scroll Lock?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127167/how-do-i-enable-scroll-lock)

Comment: Hi belacqua, No this is not a duplicate, here i have already enabled scroll lock but now a new problem, where my function keys dont work...

Comment: OK, can you give more info on what you did and what mappings you have now?